# align columns with negative and positive values in notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++, multiple-columns

I know nothing about notepad++ or python but I just tried to use both to align negative and positive values in columns. Code alignment and elastic tabstops does not quite do it. And I am digging myself a hole trying to use python from looking at other question replies on stack overflow. Is there a better way to do this? This is the data below in notepad++

```
-0.178840108 -0.62322251      0.374573025  -0.235355733 0.294963086  -0.514453843 -0.53434765  -0.038749213  
0.095089569   -0.839169017 0.374573025  -0.235355733 1.048757641  0.108306072  -0.53434765  -0.038749213
```

There are 46 lines of data.

I would like it to look like this, with positives and negatives lined up along the decimal.

```
-0.178840108 -0.62322251   0.374573025  -0.235355733 0.294963086  -0.514453843 -0.53434765  -0.038749213  
 0.095089569 -0.839169017  0.374573025  -0.235355733 1.048757641   0.108306072 -0.53434765  -0.038749213
```

Comment: Please, [format properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question and add expected result.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: I can answer to this question if it is OK with using EmEditor.